# copy of JSP custom Tag with JQuery Clone

Tags: jquery

Want to make copy of JSP custom Tag with JQuery Clone or with any other Jquery function, in a way that it can call doStart method of that JSP custom Tag.

Answer (score 0):

See `jsp` which stands for ***java server pages***, so it suggests that it would run on server.

Javascript/jQuery is a client side scripting language it always runs on client browser.

---

Your question: *Want to make copy of JSP custom Tag with JQuery Clone*

---

I would say **it is not possible** because javascript/jquery does not have the direct access of that tag. because when requested page renders all the jsp tags finally outputs the html code which is required for displaying a webpage in the browser.